# Trouble with getting litecoins in my give-me-coins account

Tags: litecoin, cgminer

I started mining litecoins yesterday on cgminer (been mining for about an hour) and so far I have got nothing in my account. 
What am I doing wrong ?

Here are two screenshots one is of cgminer, the other is of my give-me-coins account:

- http://gyazo.com/2fb18a76dedb71eb80c8a19126ab231f
- http://gyazo.com/89ca55239de31a6da4bca25072096b4e

Answer (score 1):

You need to launch cgminer with --scrypt at the command line, you will see instead of Mh/s you should be getting Kh/s.

Comment: could you teach me how to do that plz

Comment: do you have a script that you are using to launch cgminer?

Comment: im realy new to this and i dont what you mean by "scrypt" or "command line"

Comment: how do you start cgminer ?

Comment: 1) I open cgminer.exe

Comment: are you using a config file? or did you make a .bat file to start the program

Comment: 2) I insert the pool address, then the worker name, then the worker pw

Comment: yh i did make a .bat file

Comment: the problem is it just automatically closes itself

Comment: checkout this link it might help https://www.weminecryptos.com/forum/topic/540-guide-how-to-mine-litecoins-from-scratch-both-cgminer-and-guiminer-version/